# Java Shifting Array Elements Down

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, shift

I am currently struggling writing a loop that starts at a certain point in an `Array` and pushes it down to the right one spot to that a new value can be placed where the existing one is, an insertion sort.

So far I have a loop that finds which spot the value goes:

```
int hold=0;
 for (int j = 0; j < nElements; j++)   
 {
    int temp = list[j];
    if (temp <= value)
    {
       hold = j;  
    }

 }
```

I am now writing for for loop that shifts everything over.
I have:

```
for (int j = hold; j >= numElements; j--)
 {
     int temp = list[j];
     list[j] = value;

     list[j+1] = temp;

    }
```

nElements is the number of current ints I have stored in the array.

All this is doing is just inserting the first number in spot 0 when I call the method that adds the integer to the array. When the method is called again the number is not added at all.

I also cannot use predefined methods like `System.arraycopy()` . I need to code the loops.

Comment: This isn't really a question, you need to pose a question, like 'I run this code and it does...but I want it to do...."

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `System.arrayCopy()`.

You are actually not copying anything because you are starting at `hold` and looping while `j >= nElements` which should never happen.

To make room, you need to uses something like:

```
System.arrayCopy(list, hold, list, hold+1, nElements - hold - 1);
```

**Added** now we discover that we cannot use system calls:

Alternatively, if `arrayCopy` is not allowed you will need a loop such as:

```
for ( int i = nElements - 1; i > hold; i-- ) {
  list[i] = list[i-1];
}
```

Note that this code is deliberately untested as this question is likely to be homework.

Comment: this is a **terrible** quality answer. -1

Comment: I am not allowed to use predefined methods to accomplish this task. I need to make my own loop.

Comment: @user1729448: Then the question should mention that.  please edit your question.

Comment: @Doorknob - Perhaps a little better now?

Comment: @Doorknob - or perhaps `} catch(AnswerNotFinishedException anfe) { ... }` :)

Comment: The for loop I tried to fix it and still cannot get it to work

Comment: @user1729448 - Notice that you have to start at the **end** (`i = nElements-1`) and work **backwards** (`i--`) until you get to `hold` (`i > hold`).